# Scala: Prevent race condition when performing some action after one Future fails out of a sequence of futures

Tags: scala, concurrency, future

I have a mutable list of futures: ArrayBuffer[Future[Seq[T]]]

While my program is running, new Futures are added to that list over time, and complete on their own eventually. After each Future completes I perform some validation against its value.  If the value fails validation, I want to take all the completed Future's (_.isCompleted) in the mutable ArrayBuffer[Future[Seq[T]]] along with the current value and perform some action on them. I only want this action to perform once.  Once all this is over, I end my program and no longer care about the other Futures that have not been completed or that have recently been added while all this was happening.

My question is:

1. How do I avoid the race condition where 2 or more Futures complete and fail validation around the same time and end up performing the action more than once.
2. Can you spot any other possible issues that may occur.

This is my current implementation which has the race condition.  Im very new to Futures and Scala, if there is a more idiomatic way write this, especially the failure checking part, suggestions appreciated.  Thank you

```
val futures = ArrayBuffer[Future[Seq[T]]] = ArrayBuffer()

def add(future: Future[Seq[T]]): Unit = {
    futures += future

    val failures = future.map(value => if(failsValidation) throw new ValidationException)
    failures.failed.map(e => {
        val completed = futures
            .filter(_.isCompleted)
            .map(_.value.get)
            .filter(_.isSuccess)
            .map(_.get)

        someAction(completed)
    })
}
```

Comment: 1. `futures` should be `AtomicReference` otherwise you might have race condition on editing the array. You would update it in `ref.updateAndGet(...)`  to get the value of `val completed`. 2. `someAction` might be `synchronized` to avoid running it by two futures at once. 3. This logic sound very specific, if you describe what you need it for there is probably a framework which already deals with it (Akka, FS2, some ZIO library).

Comment: I used Akka to control this kind of possible concurrent events when using Futures. Or  you can take a look to https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/docs/std/ref, and https://zio.dev/version-1.x/datatypes/concurrency/ref/

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok Basically, someAction - writes to a database.

The logic that writes to the array runs in the main thread so it is sequential. The read race condition exists, but i'm not concerned with that.  The biggest issue is writing to the database twice ( possibley in tandem ).

But anyways I'll look into those frameworks you suggested.

Comment: Although I would prefer not to use a framework, since the main application doesnt have to be async

Answer (score 0):

After some thinking I was able to come up with a possible solution on my own.  Bare in mind this isn't tested in production.

One possible solution is to use a flag to prevent additional executions of the someAction logic.  To prevent the other running Futures from continuily running we can implement a Cancellable Future.

Viktor Klang has an implementation that wraps a future given a block of logic and returns the wrapped future and a cancel function.
https://viktorklang.com/blog/Futures-in-Scala-protips-6.html

So the new code will look like this.

```
// Signature of Viktor Klang's Cancellable Future - (Future[Seq[T]], () => Boolean)
val futures = ArrayBuffer[(Future[Seq[T]], () => Boolean)] = ArrayBuffer()

var alreadyDidAction = true // flag to prevent race condition

def add(future: (Future[Seq[T]], () => Boolean)): Unit = {
    futures += future

    val failures = future.map(value => if(failsValidation) throw new ValidationException)
    failures.failed
        .filter(!_.isInstanceOf[CancellationException])
        .map(_ => {
            if(alreadyDidAction) {
                alreadyDidAction = false

                futures.foreach {
                    case (_, cancel) => cancel()
                }   

                val completed = futures
                    .filter(_.isCompleted)
                    .map(_.value.get)
                    .filter(_.isSuccess)
                    .map(_.get)

                someAction(completed)
           }
        })
}
```

At first I thought the read and write operations on the flag would have to be wrapped in a synchronized block but because callbacks are executed on the main thread there will be no race condition.